# How do you handle relations in a NoSQL database?

Tags: database-design, nosql

With a standard RDMS I can find relations by using primary keys and foreign keys. If I want recent comments then I just order by a datetime. If I want all the comments by a user, then I fetch where a comment belongs to that user.

In other words, I can use indexes to filter results. *Not just the primary key.*

However, with the document and key-value NoSQL I can't figure out how I could use them for much more than a text dump. The only thing you can do is fetch the value by an ID.

**I need some examples of how you model data in NoSQL when you can no longer use indexes or filters. How do you sort and search data?**

Comment: If you're modeling relational data that has a defined schema, why are you using a schemaless, non-relational database? This seems like asking "How do you turn a screw with a hammer?"

Comment: I always thought most of what we did in this business was finding the right wrench to pound in the correct screw.  :-)

Comment: Well, you are probably right. However, some people are using NoSQL *SOMEHOW* and I can't figure out how they are doing it or what they are using it for. I'm hoping that someone here can show how an application can be built entirely on a NoSQL database when I just assume object relations are required.

Answer (score 1):

If you need secondary indexes like you're describing, then you can't just use any non-relational database. BigTable databases like Cassandra (and probably others) allow for secondary indexes.

If you need to search for things within a Key-Value store based on the *values* then you'll need to get creative. You could:
1) Create your own keys that point at the original keys and then maintain those pairs on new inserts, updates, and deletes of the original pairs.
2) Just look at every value, brute force, off-line, once a day and save the answer somewhere. Clearly this won't work if you need the new data right away.

Sorting the data will probably need to be done on the application layer or with custom sorted sets if you use technique (1) and Redis.

Comment: Actually, I was just going over MongoDB also and they both seem to support basic "WHERE" searches on secondary keys which would give 95% of SQL functionally. Apparently the *key-value* NoSQL databases are supposed to be used along side normal RDBMS (or Mongo/Cassandra) to provide simple file/text/blob storage which might out-grow a normal SQL database.

Comment: Yes, mongodb and ravendb allow for this...  relational data (conceptual) can be stored in some NoSQL offerings... however, key/value stores aren't the best suited for this IMO.  Raven/Mongo are great...

Answer (score 0):

Which NoSQL database are you using? [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/gYaDfo), for example, has support for [secondary indices](http://bit.ly/hHyxAE).